# Why latex splits a matrix into multiple lines

Tags: matrices

I have multiple matrices as shown in the code below. I have no idea why latex splits each line of the matrix on the left-hand side into multiple lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
    \vdots &  &  &  & \vdots &  &  &  &  & \vdots &  &  &  &  & \vdots &  &  &  &  & \vdots & \\
\end{bmatrix}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
$x_{00}$\\
$x_{01}$\\
$x_{02}$\\
$x_{03}$\\
\vdots\\
$x_{10}$\\
$x_{11}$\\
$x_{12}$\\
$x_{13}$\\
\vdots\\
$x_{(10)0}$\\
$x_{(10)1}$\\
$x_{(10)2}$\\
$x_{(10)3}$\\
\vdots\\
$w_0$\\
$w_1$\\
$w_2$\\
$w_3$\\
\vdots\\
$w_{10}$
\end{bmatrix}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
$\leq$\\
$\leq$\\
$\leq$\\
\vdots\\
$\leq$\\
$\leq$\\
$\leq$\\
\vdots\\
$=$\\
$=$\\
$=$\\
$=$\\
$=$\\
$=$\\
\vdots\\
$\geq$\\
$\geq$\\
$\geq$\\
\vdots\\
$=$\\
$\leq$\\
$\leq$\\
$\leq$\\
\vdots
\end{bmatrix}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
$1$\\
$1$\\
$1$\\
\vdots\\
$1$\\
$1$\\
$1$\\
\vdots\\
$1$\\
$1$\\
$0$\\
$0$\\
$0$\\
$0$\\
\vdots\\
$g_1-M$\\
$g_2-M$\\
$g_3-M$\\
\vdots\\
$0$\\
$C_1$\\
$C_1$\\
$C_1$\\
\vdots
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code produces

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 
                             
l.10 ... 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots &
                                                   0 \\
? x
```

as it has more than 10 columns, add

```
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{40}
```

You then get

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.18 $x_
        {00}$\\
?
```

delete every `$` you are already in math mode.

Do not even look at the PDF until no errors are reported. After the above changes you get

[image]

This looks better but I may have destroyed your data

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{40}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{landscape}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
    \vdots &  &  &  & \vdots &  &  &  &  & \vdots &  &  &  &  & \vdots &  &  &  &  & \vdots & \\
\end{bmatrix}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{00}\\
x_{01}\\
x_{02}\\
%x_{03}\\
\vdots\\
x_{10}\\
x_{11}\\
x_{12}\\
%x_{13}\\
\vdots\\
x_{(10)0}\\
x_{(10)1}\\
x_{(10)2}\\
%x_{(10)3}\\
\vdots\\
w_0\\
w_1\\
w_2\\
%w_3\\
\vdots\\
w_{10}
\end{bmatrix}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
\leq\\
\leq\\
\leq\\
\vdots\\
\leq\\
\leq\\
\leq\\
\vdots\\
%=\\
%=\\
%=\\
=\\
=\\
=\\
\vdots\\
\geq\\
\geq\\
\geq\\
\vdots\\
%=\\
%\leq\\
%\leq\\
\leq\\
%\vdots
\end{bmatrix}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1\\
\vdots\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
\vdots\\
1\\
1\\
0\\
%0\\
%0\\
%0\\
\vdots\\
g_1-M\\
g_2-M\\
g_3-M\\
\vdots\\
%0\\
%C_1\\
%C_1\\
C_1\\
%\vdots
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```